# Scaling and integrating existing disconnected drupal based sytems?

Tags: drupal-7, single-sign-on, scaling, drupal-8

We are currently planning to scale our current digital platforms to support a small number of number franchised businesses operating in different international locations.

Would appreciate a bit of help sense checking.

We are thinking about eventually effectively rebuilding our existing Drupal 7 website as a Drupal 8 site multisite installation -one installation for each business location (assuming that is the logical thing to do considering it is expected to release in the fall??).

We also have a separate Drupal 7 installation that is used as a system for accepting public submissions. I would like to upgrade to Drupal 8 rather than redevelop.

We will also be developing a smart phone app that gives users a view of their account and provides rewards etc... Currently these systems are all effectively disconnected.

We have two groups of existing users (currently residing in the two separate Drupal installations) that we need to migrate to our new system and somehow centralise.

We want to connect all of our systems (Drupal multisite installation, Drupal submission system, smart phone app and a CRM) and implement a single sign on mechanism

The thinking I am currently being sold is that we need to place the CRM system as a kind of central repository of account information that all systems can defer/sync to?

Does this seem logical/possible?

Could anyone provide any thoughts on all that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is logically possible.
You should manitain one json api to communicate with all your systems.
that api should managed by your core system to create & update data in different platforms.